# How do I rewrite URL's for a subdirectory of a site?

Tags: nginx

I host a mirror of the Textfiles archive, on `http://subdomain.example.com/`

Part of this mirror is a mirror of `pinouts.ru`, located on `http://subdomain.example.com/mirror/pinouts.ru/`

As you can see `http://subdomain.example.com/mirror/pinouts.ru/` (and its subpages) look pretty crappy.
This is because all links to css, images, etc in these pages are absolute. A good example is the stylesheet of the main page. The link points to `/style.css`, which attempts to retrieve `http://subdomain.example.com/styles.css` (instead of `http://subdomain.example.com/mirror/pinouts.ru/style.css`)

Is it possible to configure nginx in such a way that it rewrites these URL's?

(pinouts.ru is just one of several mirrors where I have this issue)

Comment: "in these pages are absolute" - you mean "root-relative" (starting with a slash). If it was "absolute" (ie. with a scheme and domain name) then it couldn't be simply rewritten.

Comment: They're root-relative. '/style.css/', for example.

(My original post contained the actual links to illustrate my case, but that's apparently against the rules?)

Answer (score 1):

```
Location ~ /styles.css {
        rewrite /pinouts.ru/style.css permanent;
}
```